# FluentBit Date parsing issue, opensearch taking as string

Tags: date-format, opensearch, fluent-bit

log file contains date in this format "20 Mar 2023 13:40:10,640 +0530" (month as string ). while sending to the openSearch it is taking as a string variable so unable to perform any operation on the date variable. I need to parse the date("20 Mar 2023 13:40:10,640 +0530") in this format "2023/05/20 13:40:10" which will be accepting as date variable in openSearch. I have tried to solve this problem by using lua filter script but it's not working. also can we calculate duration between 2 dates in ms and create a new variable to store the duration.

```
[PARSER]
    Name        floorSerevrDump_logs
    Format      regex
    Regex       ^(?<time>\d+ [a-zA-Z]+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+),\d+\s.\d+\s+(?<loglevel>[^\d]+)(?<floormessage_id>\d+)\]\s+(?<log>.+)
    Types       duration:integer
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S 
    Time_Keep   On


[FILTER]
Name lua
Match test_log
call extract_timestamp
code function extract_timestamp(log)local month,day,hour,min,sec = log:match('^(%d%d)%s(%u%l%l)%s(%d%d%d%d)%s(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d),(%d%d%d)%s(.)') local MON={Jan=1,Feb=2,Mar=3,Apr=4,May=5,Jun=6,Jul=7,Aug=8,Sep=9,Oct=10,Nov=11,Dec=12} local timestamp = os.time({year = os.date("*").year, month = MON[month], day = day, hour = hour, min = min, sec = sec}) return timestamp end
```

Want to update the index variable data type in openSearch or plugin to change the date format